# has anybody found a way to solve this error in wine?

Tags: python, node.js, batch-file, wine

I am trying to build an old node versions(0.7.4) and I get this error

```
python tools\\gyp_node -f msvs -G msvs_version=2010 -Dtarget_arch=ia32' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
```

that relates to this line of code in the vcbuild.bat

```
python tools\gyp_node -f msvs -G msvs_version=2010 -Dtarget_arch=%target_arch%
```

I tried to comment out the line and it fails to build and just gives this error

```
Failed to create vc project files.
```

Comment: That looks like only a part of an error message.

Comment: Make sure you include the entire error message (you currently have not) and enough code to reproduce the problem. Be as literal as you can, if you knew where the problem is and what bit is relevant, you would not be asking. See also: [mre]

Comment: my guess would be that python isn't installed and available on the path

Comment: My guess is the arguments got interpreted as part of the executable name. Some quoting mishap?

Comment: Lots of things could be a cause, without knowing precisely what you did and what output you got, it's impossible to tell. Make sure you use the actual error message for research online, too. That said, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your title conveys almost no relevant info!